# Get data with restful webservices from Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, web-services, rest, plsql, restful-architecture

I want to get data from webservices from oracle database.
But I'm looking  for it unfortunately I can't anything .
Please give me some hints.I want to accesses it with username and password in pl/sql code.
How can I do it? 
Thank you..

Comment: I haven't used this myself but have a read of [Native Oracle XML DB Web Services](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/xdb_web_services.htm) and [Oracle Base: Web Services and the Oracle Database](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/web-services-and-the-oracle-database).

Answer (score 2):

I solve it like following code.I think it will be useful .

```
declare 
  t_http_req     utl_http.req;
  t_http_resp    utl_http.resp;
  t_request_body varchar2(30000);
  t_respond      varchar2(30000);
  t_start_pos    integer := 1;
  t_output       varchar2(2000);

begin
  /*Construct the information you want to send to the webservice.
    Normally this would be in a xml structure. But for a REST-
  webservice this is not mandatory. The webservice i needed to
  call excepts plain test.*/
  t_request_body := 'the data you want to send to the webservice';

  /*Telling Oracle where the webservice can be found, what kind of request is made
    and the version of the HTTP*/
  t_http_req:= utl_http.begin_request( 'http://urlofwebservice'
                                     , 'GET'
                                     , 'HTTP/1.1');

  /*In my case the webservice used authentication with a username an password
    that was provided to me. You can skip this line if it's a public webservice.*/
  utl_http.set_authentication(t_http_req,'username','password');                                     

  /*Describe in the request-header what kind of data is send*/
  utl_http.set_header(t_http_req, 'Content-Type', 'text/xml charset=UTF-8');

  /*Describe in the request-header the lengt of the data*/
  utl_http.set_header(t_http_req, 'Content-Length', length(t_request_body));

  /*Put the data in de body of the request*/
  utl_http.write_text(t_http_req, t_request_body);


  /*make the actual request to the webservice en catch the responce in a
    variable*/
  t_http_resp:= utl_http.get_response(t_http_req);

  /*Read the body of the response, so you can find out if the information was
    received ok by the webservice.
    Go to the documentation of the webservice for what kind of responce you
    should expect. In my case it was:
  <responce>
    <status>ok</status>
  </responce>
  */
  utl_http.read_text(t_http_resp, t_respond);


         dbms_output.put_line(t_respond);


  /*Some closing?1 Releasing some memory, i think....*/
  utl_http.end_response(t_http_resp);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [UTL_HTTP package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_http.htm)

Comment: Thank you for your advice.But a lot of piece of code in there.and very complex